# How do you access angular directive isolated scope variables in link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html

```
<test something="hey"> </test>
```

Here is my directive

```
app.directive('test', ['', function (l) {


return {
    restrict: 'EC',
    replace: true,
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        something: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '<div something="none"></div>',
    link: function (scope, elm) {
        // how do I access something in link?
```

Is there anyway I can access scope variable `something` in link function

```
scope.something  // doesn't return anything
```

Comment: create demo that replicates problem

Comment: I tried plunker, and jsfiddle, but angular js doesn't seems to play nice with either of those

Comment: angular works fine in both those sites.

Comment: The whole plunker site is built in angular ... works great there. Can start a whole app in just a few clicks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a variable named `hey` on the parent scope? I believe you are passing the variable `hey` instead of a string (I'm assuming you are trying to pass a string). You should try this:

```
<test something="'hey'"> </test>
```

or

```
<test something="{{hey}}"> </test>
```

Directive binding is always tricky, [this](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/) is a good read.

Let me know if it worked! :)